# Material Theme Android Action Bar Style Generator

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design

Is there Android Action Bar Style Generator for the Material Themes ?

I'm looking for something like this http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/ but with the support new **Material Style** for Android (not Holo style).

Thanks for advance :)

Comment: That generator never worked for me. No matter what I did. I can use a really old SDK or a really new version, but it always gave me trouble. Once you use compatibility to make it work, the style/theme is destroyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Material theme uses tinting and simple shapes to generate UI. You don't need any generator, because there's no 9-patches nor any other graphic. Just set your colors in your theme (primary, accent, etc.) and you're ready to go.

Answer (score 4):

As described in the tool:

**DEPRECATED**: Consider using [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) or its [support library equivalent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html).

Use the AppCompat library and just set these values in your styles.xml

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_color</item>

    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_darker_color</item>

    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated, which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight, and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->

</style>
```